# My List of lists of objects are equal to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, arraylist

Soo, i'm trying to create a list of lists in python. Here is the code:

```
class CacheL1: 
def __init__(self):
    self.vias = []

    for via in range(2):
        self.conjuntos = []
        for conj in range(4):
            self.conjunto = Via(0, 0, 0)
            self.conjuntos.append(self.conjunto)
        self.vias.append(self.conjuntos[:])
```

All positions should have different objects, but I am storing the same lists in different positions.

For example, the object of position [0][0] is a different object of [0][1], and this is what i expected. But the object of position [0][0] is the same object of [1][0], what i'm not expecting.

I've searched a similar question, but i couldn't find. Sorry if this is a recurrent question. If i wasn't   clear, i will try again(as u can see english isn't my main language).

Edit, my Via:

```
class Via:
def __init__(self, mru, validade, bloco):
    self.mru = mru
    self.validade = validade

    self.bloco = bloco
    if type(bloco) == int:
        self.tag = 0
```

Comment: "But the object of position [0][0] is the same object of [1][0]" note with tthe code you've show above, if I fix your indentation error and add a reasonable implementation for `class Via:...` note, **please** always provide a [mcve]

Comment: As an aside, I see no reason to make `self.conjunto` and `self.conjuntos` instance attributes, they should probably just be local variables?

Comment: Your example can't be run without knowing the contents of the 'Via' function, which seems to be something you have defined.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i'm trying to create independent lists, but they are keeping memory references. I've added Via

Comment: I've already explained to you that isnt happening with the code you have provided. You *must* provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, something we can run ourselves. If instantiate a `c = CacheL1()` object, then `c.vias[0][0] is c.vias[1][0]` is false.